# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 'appendTo'

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This is my page.](http://crelation.com/freeMag/Viewer)

And i got an error is

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 'appendTo'

I have not idea what happend to this.

Error occur in

```
$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).appendTo($rgGallery);
```

Can you please help this?

Thanks in advence.

Comment: Is jquery library loaded properly or at top of any other plugin?

Comment: `$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} )` returns an empty array `[]`. Therefore, trying to append it anywhere isn't going to work

Comment: it should like `.appendTo($("#rgGallery"))`

Comment: Which jquery.tmpl library do you use?

Comment: I can't find any element for $('#img-wrapper-tmpl'); what this selector is pointing to?

Comment: @neelshah `var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery')` is in the code, so that is fine.

Comment: @LeeTaylor You are right, i have no this element.., i think i removed the $('#img-wrapper-tmpl') before.
Now i know what to do, thanks you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have `#img-wrapper-tmpl` element in your page, that's the reason your selector is returning null or empty array and based on which you got this error.

Comment: Yeah..., i have no this element. I will try to comment them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rgGallery.append($('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ));
```

Comment: How is that different?

Comment: @VisioN It doesn't require `$.fn.tmpl()` to return a jQuery object and would allow it to be a simple string. Of course I had no idea if that solved the problem due to the question lacking a lot of information.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you're missing a parameter to your .tmpl() function.

```
$.tmpl( template, {itemsCounts : itemsCount}).appendTo($rgGallery);
```

or

```
$.tmpl($('#img-wrapper-tmpl'), {itemsCounts : itemsCount}).appendTo($rgGallery);
```

Where template is a variable that contains the HTML markup of what you to render.  Based on your code, you're using the [this plugin.](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

Re: You should also specify `$('#img-wrapper-tmpl')`

Comment: What is `$('#img-wrapper-tmpl')`?  There is nothing on the page with that ID.

Comment: @Archer it's not there. the asker must include that element/variable as well. :)

Comment: Yes, so your answer is incorrect.  The problem is that the element does not exist.